# On pied-piping in direct question and indirect question vs. relative clauses

Tags: pied-piping

I am Miguel, whose first language is Japanese. This time, I have very naive or trivial question on pied-piping in English.

It seems to be said that the pied-piping takes place more often in relative clauses than in question sentences. My question is to what extent English native speakers allow pied-piping in wh-questions. I made several examples. If possible, could you grade these examples?

1. I heard bad information **according to which** my grandmother passed away.
2. I don't know the picture **of who(m)** John likes.
3. I don't know **of whom** John likes the picture.
4. I don't know **whom** John likes the picture of.
5. I wonder **after which party** John went to the hotel.
6. I wonder **which party** John went to the hotel **after**.
7. The picture **of whom** does John like?
8. **Of whom** does John like the picture?
9. **Who(m)** does John like the picture **of**?
10. **After which party** did John go to the hotel?
11. **Which party** did John go to the hotel?

If the sentence is completely acceptable, grade it as 5. If it is totally unacceptable, assign 1.

example: (1) 5, (2) 2, (3) .....

This question asks your acceptability, but not formal grammaticalness. Even if you think that is prescriptive, as long as you can accept the sentence, grade it higher.

I am very looking forward to hearing your answer!

Comment: I'm afraid questions of opinion are off-topic on all SE sites.

Comment: I had to look up [pied-piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping) as it applies to this context. Is there even a gradient? From a brief look at the wikipedia article I linked, it seems to be a binary thing - either it's pied-piped or it isn't.

Comment: @Lawrence: The gradient described in the question is for acceptability, not for whether or not it is pied-piping. Miguel is asking how acceptable each example is. I think it is a good question, although perhaps a bit long. It will require a somewhat extensive discussion for a good answer.

Comment: @StoneyB: Linguistic acceptability is not primarily a matter of opinion; it is a verifiable scientific fact. If you are unfamiliar with the concept, please read the following blog post:
[Acceptability Judgements](http://facultyoflanguage.blogspot.com/2013/09/acceptability-judgements.html)

Comment: I think 1 and 5 may be marginally acceptable(2).  The others, not(1).

Comment: @sumelic I see what you mean now. I initially interpreted the question as "to what extent do people consider these to be pied-piped questions", that is, "allow"ing the piped-piped form into questions. Reinterpreting the question along the lines you mention, pied-piping becomes part of the motivation for the question, but the question itself requests a grading that doesn't depend on knowing what pied-piping means. In that case: 10 (10) e.g. if asked by a police officer given a context of multiple parties; 1, 4, 5 are barely acceptable (2); I'd rate the rest *unacceptable* (1).

Comment: @sumelic It's a **poll**: OP doesn't ask for established judgments, but for our individual judgments--that is, our several opinions. These indeed may be aggregated, tentatively, as the sort of Acceptability Judgment the post you link discusses ; but there would be serious questions about the relevance of the sample.

Comment: (Most of the Miguels I know are Spanish or Portuguese not Japanese) This question will likely be closed as a poll question, but I can report that all the pied-piping versions are completely unnatural and virtually unheard in actual speech by native speakers.

Comment: The issue of pied-piping seems to be how the wh-word pulls with it a modifier. 

        a. She bought the red house.
        b. Which house did she buy ___? - The interrogative word which has pied-piped the noun house.
        c. *Which did she buy ___ house? - The sentence is bad because pied-piping has not occurred.

Thus, what difference does it make whether we rate these good or bad? (I'd accept only #10).

Comment: I might have agreed with GEdgar but if 5 is acceptable then how could 6 or 10 not be? Either way, I think sumelic is more than largely correct about acceptability, further to which it doesn’t seem to me to matter whether it’s a ‘poll’ question. Either one person comes up with a definitive answer that everyone else accepts or it’s a question of opinion, however well-informed.  

Like Lawrence I had to look up ‘pied-piping.’ I confess, I found Wikipedia's explanation of pied-piping wholly impenetrable; to the extent I could imagine interpretations with meaning, wholly pointless.

More…

Comment: If it’s true that in ‘Which house did she buy  ___?’ the interrogative has pied-piped the noun, that seems to be because the commentator wanted more to coign a new phrase than to accept a structure nearly everyone else recognized.

Either way, what on Earth is that ‘buy ___?’ doing, please? Wasn’t ‘Which house did she buy?’ complete as it stood? What could any replacement for ‘___’ possibly contribute?

More…

Comment: Wikipedia seems to present the b. question as a re-structuring of the a. statement, which would be to say that generally, questions are re-structurings of statements… true on the same level that statements are re-structurings of questions; equally, otherwise meaningless.


Slightly different doubts apply to the relationship between c. question ‘Which did she buy ___ house?’ and either the b. question or the a. statement but the conclusion ‘The sentence is bad because pied-piping has not occurred’ seems worse than a desire to coign a phrase where none is needed.

Thanks for your patience